# Stop animation in VivaGraph.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can stop the animation for the nodes in VivaGraph.JS
everything is great but nodes still moving and some nodes come out in the frame.
I can't use this example :
https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/blob/master/demos/other/constantLayout.html
because is not good for me the determinate for every node a position. 
My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>02. Custom node appearance. Vivagraph SVG tutorial.</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/vivagraph.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main () {
            // Create a graph:
            var graph = Viva.Graph.graph();

            for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
            graph.addNode(i, '91bad8ceeec43ae303790f8fe238164b');
            }


            var graphics = Viva.Graph.View.svgGraphics();

            graphics.node(function(node) {

                var url = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/' + node.data; 

                return Viva.Graph.svg('image')
                     .attr('width', 24)
                     .attr('height', 24)
                     .link(url); 
            });

            graphics.placeNode(function(nodeUI, pos) {

                nodeUI.attr('x', pos.x - 12).attr('y', pos.y - 12);
            });

            // Render the graph with our customized graphics object:
            var renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
                    graphics : graphics
                });
            renderer.run();
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body, svg { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body onload='main()'>

</body>
</html>
```

I wish I explain good my problem, someone can help me please.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following methods of the renderer object to accomplish this.

To start the rendering - `renderer.run();`
To pause the rendering - `renderer.pause();`
To resume the rendering - `renderer.resume();`
To reset the scale of the rendering to fit all elements - `renderer.reset();`
To remove the rendering - `renderer.dispose();`

Hope this is helpful...